# F3-F5 keys incorrectly behaving as audio keys

Tags: linux, keyboard, keymap, media-keys, function-keys

I don't know if this is a configuration issue or a hardware issue, but I have a Kinesis Advantage USB keyboard and for some reason the F3-F5 keys aren't responding as they used to. They don't respond to anything and, when I tried using F5 on Emacs, it said `<XF86AudioNext> is undefined`, so I guess it's a weird mapping problem.

---

Any idea how I could remap them to the original meaning?

Comment: How do you like those things?
I've always been interested in trying one, but never really found anyone with one I could poke at, or heard any real reviews.

Comment: I'm very satisfied with mine. I started having pain after a translation gig (a lot more uninterrupted typing than programming) and this keyboard (along with other preventive practices) significantly helped stop it from reappearing. It's very comfy :)

Answer (score 9):

You have the Multimedia Group features enabled (=n).  To turn off, activate the master settings:

To change a setting, pressing and hold the “=” key in the number row (above the Tab key) on your Advantage keyboard, then tap the appropriate second key. To turn off all settings in a group, activate one of the master settings (=m, =p, or =w).

Multimedia Group features, =n

- <kbd>F3</kbd> - Previous track
- <kbd>F4</kbd> - Play, Pause
- <kbd>F5</kbd> - Next track
- <kbd>F9</kbd> - Mute
- <kbd>F10</kbd> - Volume down
- <kbd>F11</kbd> - Volume up
- <kbd>Pause</kbd> - Stop

Comment: http://kinesis-ergo.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/advantage-usb-manual.pdf link to manual with more detail

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Keyboard Shortcuts section of your desktop environment configuration and map them.

Comment: Keyboard shortcuts map key combinations to desktop environment actions. What I want is to map keys to keys or, preferably, find out why the default mapping is not working anymore.